# What is this weird futuristic font?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

[image]

Please help me identify this weird futuristic font. It has some very characteristic letters, so it should be easy to pinpoint if you know it.

However, I tried many recognition tools (and reddit) and the closest I got was Gaoel, but that's not quite it... https://www.whatfontis.com/CR_Gaoel-otf-400.font?text=BRiGHTFUTURE

Some suggested modified Avenir or Gotham, but it's definitely not Avenir if you look at the R, and Gotham is also not likely as C, E and S have a bit bigger curvature than in Gotham. I still suspect it's a font, especially given how similar it is to Gaoel. Any guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base font is probably Gotham Medium by [Hoefler & Co.](https://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/overview/). And then some chopping...

[image]

Comment: I think you nailed it! :)

Answer (score 1):

It definitely is a modified version of Montserrat.

[image]

Comment: It’s close, the “G” and “R” are noticeably different though

Answer (score -1):

[image: LOGOTYPE from fonts.com]

It looks like a modified version of Gerald Gallo's Logotype

Comment: When suggesting a font please link to the location of the font and include a screenshot of the font in action.  It adds value to an answer and will help others see if your answer is correct.

Comment: It's the kind of the same design idea, but it would need so much modification, you'd better be off starting with Arial Bold.